# How do I communicate with the Ubuntu kernel team?

Tags: kernel

How do I communicate with the Ubuntu kernel team?

Comment: When you are answering your own question it strikes me as a bit odd for part of the answer to be the body of the question.

Comment: 1. I'm trying to get some of the most frequently asked questions answered here so people don't have to got to the kernel team wiki pages.

2. I want to point people at the wiki pages as a resource.

3. It doesn't make sense to me to have the question and the body of the question be the same text.

Answer (score 7):

The Ubuntu Kernel Team is located in disparate cities throughout the world. We utilize IRC to communicate with each other as well as the Ubuntu user community. The team hangs out on the #ubuntu-kernel channel on [FreeNode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat). There is usually someone from the team in the channel 24hrs a day Monday through Friday. If you do join the channel, please be patient after asking your question, if you don't get an answer right away.

A good place to look for answers to these kinds of questions is the [Ubuntu Kernel Team's wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel) specifically the [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ).